# MVC5 Text Box Input Mask With Placeholder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to implement an Input Mask to force a two character entry. If the field is empty, I would like to display a placeholder. This works fine with fields that I do not mask the input, but it does not seem to work with masked inputs. Any other solutions? Here is a snippet of the field:

```
<dd style="display: none" id="stateEditor">@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.State, new { mask = "aa", htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "NJ" } })</dd>
```

Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to set placeholder in htmlAttributes. Set placeholder the same as mask attribute. hope, it will help.

```
<dd style="display: none" id="stateEditor">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.State, new { mask = "aa", placeholder = "NJ" })</dd>
```